# Justifying regular language

Tags: finite-automata

I have been given the question "Is the language 010 ∪ 101 regular? Justify your answer."

It is regular and as it can be accepted by an NFA (Draw NFA). Is this correct?

Comment: OK, so you've given us a question and answered it. What part are you unsure about? What are you looking for help with? Grading your solutions is a job for your TA or professor.

Answer (score 2):

A language is regular if it is accepted by a DFA.

It is also regular if it is accepted by a NFA (as every NFA can be converted into an equivalent DFA).

I suggest look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) to know what constitutes a regular language.

Answer (score 1):

A language is regular if and only if it can be written as a regular expression (the CS kind, not the Perl kind you see in most programming languages). Equivalently, if and only if it can be recognized by a DFA, or if and only if it can be recognized by an NFA; all three of these are equivalent.

In this case, the regular expression `010+101` expresses your language. Thus the language is regular.